Hit or Miss | i3-9100F+1060-3G in 2024 A.D
Could you guys help me with the configuration of this 2nd-hand budget PC? I'm wondering if it's suitable for rendering FDH videos on CapcutPC (main purpose) and also for playing CS2 (secondary purpose).
MSI H310M Pro
Intel Core i3-9100F
Zotac GTX 1060-3G
16GB DDR4 Kingmax RAM
FSP AX400 Power Supply
IDKY SSD 250GB
Tks :'>

Probably? What resolution/settings are you looking to play CS2 at? Also, is this being built from parts you already own, or are you purchasing used parts for this rig?

PC Configuration Evaluation

Motherboard

Model: MSI H310M Pro
Details: Supports 9th Gen Intel CPUs, adequate for budget builds. (Good to go)


CPU

Model: Intel Core i3-9100F
Performance: Suitable for 1080p video rendering on CapcutPC, though not the fastest.


Graphics Card

Model: Zotac GTX 1060-3G
Capability: Can handle Full HD video editing and CS2 gaming. (May need upgrade for modern games)


RAM

Capacity: 16GB DDR4 Kingmax
Efficiency: Sufficient for video editing and gaming tasks.


Power Supply

Model: FSP AX400
Power: 400W, adequate for the current setup. (Consider higher wattage for future upgrades)


Storage

Type: IDKY SSD
Size: 250GB
Note: Fast but limited storage; additional space may be needed for large files.



Overall it should do fairly well at least until you are able to get something with a little more headroom, hope this helps. Enjoy building!

Thank you so much <3

I also want to add that the just because the i3 isn't the fastest it will still do what you need it to do although it might be slower than a CPU that is more modern with more cores, it will still handle what you want although slower times such as rendering but that is usually more based off the GPU and depending what program you use to render videos you can set if you want to use the GPU or CPU for rendering.

Intel i3 are a waste of money, and you're far better going with AMD instead for better performance and bang for buck. Will mean you need to change the board as well.
In your build, your CPU is going to bottleneck your GPU, and your PSU is a bit on the light side as well.

His questions wasn't wether he should upgrade or not but rather if this setup is effiecient enough for the tasks he want's to perform, of course there are options better but your suggestion was to basically build a whole new system....
